# npm ERR cb() never called error while installing polymer-modulizer

Tags: node.js, npm, polymer

I am trying to install polymer-modulizer globally (npm install -g polymer-modulizer)

The installation process failed with no description of failure except the below one
npm ERR! cb() never called!

**Reproduction Steps:**

```
npm install -g polymer-cli

npm install -g polymer-modulizer
```

**Last few lines of the log:**

5318 timing npm Completed in 33104ms

5319 error cb() never called!

5320 error This is an error with npm itself. Please report this error at:

5321 error https://npm.community

**Platform Info**

```
$ npm --versions
{ npm: '6.9.0',
  ares: '1.15.0',
  cldr: '33.1',
  http_parser: '2.8.0',
  icu: '62.1',
  modules: '64',
  napi: '3',
  nghttp2: '1.34.0',
  node: '10.15.3',
  openssl: '1.1.0j',
  tz: '2018e',
  unicode: '11.0',
  uv: '1.23.2',
  v8: '6.8.275.32-node.51',
  zlib: '1.2.11' }

$ node -p process.platform
win32
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is resolved. On analysis found that there was a weird firewall rule within my organization that didn't allowed me to download on of the dependent certificate (Bittorrent.json). I tried re-installing in a machine with no restriction and it got installed without any issue.

Answer (score -1):

cb() never called! **Solved!**

> Please Don't use sudo to install node, npm and packages!

## Downloading and installing Node.js and npm

To publish and install packages to and from the public npm registry or your company’s npm Enterprise registry, you must install Node.js and the npm command line interface using either a Node version manager or a Node installer. We strongly recommend using a Node version manager to install Node.js and npm. We do not recommend using a Node installer, since the Node installation process installs npm in a directory with local permissions and can cause permissions errors when you run npm packages globally.

**Official NPM Docs**
https://docs.npmjs.com/downloading-and-installing-node-js-and-npm

**Official NVM repository**
https://github.com/creationix/nvm